# Not able to rename pdf file while downloading in Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, pdf, axios

I am trying to download the pdf file from the server using javascript.
This is my url.
https://domainurl.amazonaws.com/f6c3b-72c3-4a5-b489-c798e64c4d.pdf?....

I tried in two ways.

1. The current name of the file is fetching from url (f6c3b-72c3-4a5-b489-c798e64c4d.pdf). The below method is not overriding the existing name because of cross origin request.

   ````
    var link = document.createElement("a");
    link.href = uril;
    link.download = `test.pdf`;
    document.body.appendChild(link);
    link.click();
    document.body.removeChild(link);```
   ````
2. In the second method, i am trying to get that pdf using axios request. server is blocking this because of cors issue.

   ````
        axios({
        url: 'http://api.dev/file-download', //your url
        method: 'GET',
        responseType: 'blob', // important
    }).then((response) => {
        const url = window.URL.createObjectURL(new Blob([response.data]));
        const link = document.createElement('a');
        link.href = url;
        link.setAttribute('download', 'file.pdf'); //or any other extension
        document.body.appendChild(link);
        link.click();
    }); ```
   ````

is there any other way to download pdf file using javascript?